# Rails: Show time when it's not 00:00 or 12:00 from a DateTime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime, strftime

In my rails app I have a datetime field, which defaults to 12:00 when time is not specified. I only intend to display time is not 00:00 or 12:00, if it's 00:00 then I only want to display date and not time. It there's time other than 12:00 or 00:00 then I want to display both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
time = datetime_field.strftime("%I:%M")
if time == '12:00'
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Hope that helps!